# File Not Found : The requested Operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application using Adobe Creative SDK and 
When I tried to Build my application then this error shows:

> Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   D:\Computing\Study\Practice\AndroidPractice\PhotoUtility\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png
>   (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a
>   user-mapped section open)

I already tried several thing but solution is not there.
Please Help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its referring to an image in the build directory, so my guess is that you've got the specified file open in another program, which prevents the build system from overwriting it. (Or some other operation that affects the content of the file)

Comment: I am not opening anything except android studio.What other program can try to open an image inside the build system??