# Error when saving to a mapped drive in Sublime only: cannot save a file with a user-mapped section open

Tags: windows, sublimetext3

When I try to save a file in sublime from a mapped network drive I get an error:

> Unable to save Y:\MySite\index.html
>   Error: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section

This error does not happen in Notepad, and is coming from Sublime Text rather than windows, which makes me think Sublime is trying to do something funky during the save process.

What I've tried:

- [The file is open somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949021/file-not-found-the-requested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-file-with-a-us). **No**, I can save the file in Notepad.
- [There may be an issue with user permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150122/cannot-write-on-a-mapped-drive-using-impersonation) **Maybe**, however I'm not sure how to fix it. 

  *The linked post is not specific. I shared the folder by*
  Right-Click > Properties > Sharing > Share, added "Everyone", and gave them "Read/Write" permission. 
  *Could it be that "Everyone" doesn't cover the Sublime user? (Note: I have tried to run sublime as admin, to no avail)*

---

### **More Details:**

**Environment:**

- My local computer ("The Host") hosts a Windows 7 Virtual Machine ("The Guest"), which is running Jetty
- Jetty serves folders from `webapps` as web servers
- I set up `webapps` to be shared with `Everyone`
- On the host I mapped `webapps` so I can edit files locally.

Here's a pic of my Network Folder setup:

[image]

**The Issue:**

When I locally edit a `webapps` file in Sublime, and Jetty is running in the guest, I get this error when I try to save it:

[image]

However, if I edit the same file in Notepad it works fine.

---

This seems like a Sublime error rather than a windows error, meaning it's perhaps trying to do something funky with the file rather than saving it. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Joakim Erdfelt's answer to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44960406/1152809) I got this figured out!

This is an issue with windows' memory buffering, but you can fix it in a Jetty config file. [See the docs for more info](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/troubleshooting-locked-files-on-windows.html). Here's what I did:

1. Find your `webdefault.xml` file.

   - Mine was in C:\Place_where_Jetty_was_installed\Jetty\etc\
2. Open it and search for `UseFileMappedBuffer`. Look for this:

   ```
   <init-param>
     <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```
3. Set param-value to false

   ```
   <param-value>false</param-value>
   ```