# Is there a way to unlock all http methods without changing the war file?

Tags: jetty

I have a `.war` file deployed in Jetty (I didn't build it, and it's not possible to create a new instance).

An OPTIONS request to `http://example.com/rest/object/{uuid}`responds with `HEAD, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS`. The people that built the war claim that it's not an issue with their file.

### **Is there a Jetty config file I can change to allow all the http methods?**

If this is something I have to do in a Jetty Java file, I am a Jetty noob, so please be verbose, or point me to some docs that I can read.

*Note: I can `POST` via CURL, but not via http...*

Edit: (I was posting to a different Endpoint with CURL)

Answer (score 2):

<sup><sub>This is not an answer to the question I posted, but it allowed me to understand what was happening, which lead to the question being irrelevant for my particular issue. With that being said, I won't mark this as the answer in the event it is answerable (which I don't think it is, you'll see why in a minute).</sub></sup>

**The short answer** is I was trying to POST to an endpoint that expects the object to already exist:

```
http://example.com/rest/object/{uuid}
```

What I should have done was use an endpoint, where if you POST, it understands you want to create a new object:

```
http://example.com/rest/object
```

---

**The longer answer**

Let's say you have a REST Endpoint that allows you to get a specific object, like this:

```
http://example.com/rest/object/{uuid}
```

Since you're dealing with a specific object, you typically wouldn't want to POST a new object there. POST means 'create a new object'. If you *were* able to POST there, you'd essentially be overwriting that Object... and that's what [PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) is for, [but it's debatable](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/why_put_and_delete.html). Also, PUT wasn't an option either...

So, because of its subjective nature, some [Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226108/what-is-a-web-service-in-plain-english) limit request methods so you must do it the way the architects intended. The REST Server I am running doesn't have much in the way of documentation, so I was unaware of these restrictions, and am still puzzled by it.

What I thought I was doing was saying "OK, I want to create an object with this id. So if I POST my data to that specific UUID, the server will know I want to create a new object." What I should have been saying is "OK, I want to create a new object. It's UUID is already defined in the data, so all I need to do is send it to the endpoint that handles those objects, and expects a POST." Like this:

```
http://example.com/rest/object
```

Comment: The servlet spec also has a very specific behavior. Look at the source for `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` and its `doOptions()` method. That's the default implementation.  Specific servlets can override the doOptions() behavior to perform its own behavior (like your REST library is likely doing)